# Find the first preceeding value different from the condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the position in pos1 and the sampling time in t.s. In addition I have a threshold/hysteresis which is on both sides (positive and negative).

```
  n t.s.       pos1     pos2     pos3  X   side
  1   0  0.0000000 0.000000 0.000000 NA MIDDLE
  2  78 -0.4541016 1.430664 1.430664 NA MIDDLE
  3 109 -0.4199219 1.430664 1.430664 NA MIDDLE
  4 147 -0.4150391 1.430664 1.430664 NA MIDDLE
  5 197 -0.4345703 1.430664 1.425781 NA MIDDLE
  6 247 -0.4541016 1.430664 1.430664 NA MIDDLE
```

In this case, Hysteresis= 0.5/-0.5. There is a light that is turned on as soon as pos1 > Hysteresis and it won´t turn of until pos1 < -0.5. For that I created and additional variable in my dataframe (side) which tells me if pos1 is above 0.5 (ON), in between 0.5 and -0.5 (middle), or below -0.5 (OFF).

I would like to make a variable (let´s say light) that have only two possibilities ON/OFF. For that I need to assign to middle to one of the two, and this depends on the last different side factor (ON/OFF).

I´m having problems finding a function finding the preceeding variables after the condition middle is met.

Comment: I dont really understand what you want, so you have a variable which can take two values: ON/OFF, when does it take the value ON and when the value OFF?? which conditions (values) in the other variables and in which variables do have to be met?? and what is hysteresis? I only see pos1, pos2, etc. ??? one function which looks at preceding values is the `lag` function in the `dplyr`package

Comment: Hysteresis means that the current state depends not only on the current value of an external parameter (here  `pos1`), but also on the history of the subject. In this case a value of `pos1=0.2` could be connected to a light that is switched on or to one that is switched off, depending on the sign of the last occurrence of a value with `abs(pos1)>0.5`. The goal is to identify the ON/OFF sequences given the changes of `pos1`. In my opinion this is a very interesting question.

Comment: @grrgrrbla I don't see how the function `lag` could be applied here since it is unknown how far back in the series one has to look in order to find a relevant signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I can suggest at the moment. Given a sequence of values of `pos1`, the state of the light switches from ON to OFF in the case of value `pos1 < -0.5` and from OFF to ON in the case of a value `pos1 > 0.5`.

The state of the light (ON/OFF) is encoded in the variable `state`, with a value of `1` for ON and `0` for OFF:

```
set.seed(1234)
n_length <- 100 # As an example we look at 100 consecutive states / signals
pos1 <- rnorm(n_length) # normally distributed sequence of signals with mean=0 
switch_on <- (pos1 > 0.5) # potential signals to turn on the light
switch_off <- (pos1 < -0.5) # potential switch-off signals
state <- vector(length=n_length) 
check_switch <- function(state, switch_off, switch_on){
  if(state == 1 && switch_off) state <- 0
  if(state == 0 && switch_on) state <- 1
  return(state)
}
state[1] <- 1 # the default initial state is chosen as "ON". 
state[1] <- check_switch(state[1],switch_off[1],switch_on[1])
for (i in 2:n_length){
  state[i] <- state[i-1]
  state[i] <- check_switch(state[i], switch_off[i], switch_on[i])
}
#> head(cbind(pos1,state),10)
#            pos1 state
# [1,] -1.2070657     0
# [2,]  0.2774292     0
# [3,]  1.0844412     1
# [4,] -2.3456977     0
# [5,]  0.4291247     0
# [6,]  0.5060559     1
# [7,] -0.5747400     0
# [8,] -0.5466319     0
# [9,] -0.5644520     0
#[10,] -0.8900378     0
```

Unfortunately, this is not the type of popular one-line vectorized solution.  I'm not sure if it can be put in a significantly shorter form, but maybe somebody finds a more compact answer. In any case I hope that the code is helpful and that it produces the correct result.

Comment: Thank you, I just run it on R and it works fine. Below I wrote with what I manage at the end to do that. Your code is much more professional though!

Comment: Thank you :) I'm glad I could help, and I think it's great that you found a solution on your own and that the results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours I came up with this solution, much less efficient than your solution RHertel (I guess). Both of them work so is a good proof of concept.

```
data$side<-vector("character", length = lengthExp)
for(i in 1:lengthExp){
  if (data$pos1[i]>=Hysteresis)
    data$side[i]<- "ON"
  if (data$pos1[i]>= -Hysteresis && data$pos1[i]<= Hysteresis)
    data$side[i]<- "MIDDLE"
  if (data$pos1[i]<= -Hysteresis)
    data$side[i]<- "OFF"
}

data$light<-vector("character", length = lengthExp)
for(i in 1:lengthExp){
  if(i==1 && data$side[i]=="MIDDLE") data$light <- "OFF"
  if(i>1){
    if (data$side[i]== "ON")
      data$light[i]<- "ON"
    if (data$side[i]== "MIDDLE") 
      data$light[i]<- data$light[i-1]
    if (data$side[i]== "OFF")
      data$light[i]<- "OFF"
  }
}
```